# Draw a buffer with subbuffers webgl

Tags: javascript, webgl

How I can draw a buffer with sub-buffers in webgl? 
For Example I have  a different points to create a line but contains parts that I don't want to connect.

```
///Example code
    var lines = [
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
        [5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7]
    ];
    var colores = [
        [10, 43, 100, 1, ],
        [0, 100, 0, 1],
        [100, 100, 0, 1]
    ]
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        lineVertexPositionBuffer[i] = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, lineVertexPositionBuffer[i]);
        lineVertexPositionBuffer[i].itemSize = 3;
        lineVertexPositionBuffer[i].numItems = line[i].length / 3;

        colorVertexBuffer[i] = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVertexBuffer[i]);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colores[i]), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        colorVertexBuffer[i].itemSize = 4;
        colorVertexBuffer[i].numItems = colores[i].length / 4;

    }

    function DrawScene() {
        for (var i = 0; i < lineVertexPositionBuffer.length; i++) {
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVertexBuffer[i]);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(currentProgram.textureCoordAttribute, colorVertexBuffer[i].itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, lineVertexPositionBuffer[i]);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(currentProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_STRIP, 0, lineVertexPositionBuffer[i].numItems);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gl.drawElements and provide index list that tells GL which vertices are actually used. To allow drawing multiple segments with single call you can use gl.LINES. If you have points p0..p6 where 0,1,2 and 4,5 are connected you need indexes to be 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5. Basically two indexes from pair that tells gl which vertices to connect with lines. You could even do indexes out of order like 0, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3.

To put vertices and color data to same buffer you can either interleave them or put them after each other like

```
/* interleaved. Padding isn't mandator but it keeps math simpler
   and GPUs often prefer cache aligned data. */
[x0, y0, z0, pad0, r0, g0, b0, a0,
x1, y1, z1, pad1, r1, g1, b1, a1,...]
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 4*4*2, 0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLocation, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 4*4*2, 4*4);

/* n positions followed by n colors */
[x0, y0, z0, pad0,
x1, y1, z1, pad1,
...
r0, g0, b0, a0,
r1, g1, b1, a1,...] /* to WebGLBuffer in ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING */
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 4*4, 0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLocation, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 4*4, 4*4*n);

/* Index buffer to draw lines between vertices 0->1,1->3, 1->4 and 7->9 with gl.LINES */
[0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 7, 9] /* to WebGLBuffer in ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING */

/* gl.drawArrays can't duplicate same drawing
   because vertices are referenced out of order. drawElements 
   also allows using a vertex for multiple lines. */
gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, 4*2, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

/* Alternative with only inorder but skiped vertices that can be duplicated with DrawArrays.
   Connections are 0->1, 1->2, 4->5 and 6->7*/
[0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7] /* to WebGLBuffer in ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING */
gl.drawElements(GL.LINES, 4*2, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

/* Same rendering with multiple drawArrays calls */
gl.DrawArrays(gl.LINE_STRIP, 0, 3) /* Draw strip from 0 to 3 */
gl.DrawArrays(gl.LINES, 4, 2) /* Draw line between 4 and 5 */
gl.DrawArrays(gl.LINES, 6, 2) /* Draw line between 6 and 7 */
```

Does that help you to find the answer?

Comment: Is ok, but i need that is dynamic. Because the lines could change, adding more or delete it.

Comment: @Julio You can modify both index buffer and vertex buffer with BufferSubData. But index buffer is smaller than vertex buffer so allocating a new one and filling it complete is cheaper than modifying vertices in runtime. But did I understand your question incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do. If your lines are dynamic just put them in the buffer and draw, then put new lines in the buffer and draw, rinse and repeat.

```js
var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl", {
  preserveDrawingBuffer: true, 
});

var program = twgl.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);
var positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position");
var colorLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");

var buffer = gl.createBuffer();

function putRandomLinesInBuffer(buf, numLines) {
  var points = new Float32Array(numLines * 4);
  for (var i = 0; i < numLines; ++i) {
    points[i * 4 + 0] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    points[i * 4 + 1] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    points[i * 4 + 2] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    points[i * 4 + 3] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  }
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, points, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}

function render() {
  var numLines = 5 + Math.random() * 10 | 0;
  putRandomLinesInBuffer(buffer, numLines);
  
  gl.useProgram(program);
  
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl._ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  
  gl.uniform4f(colorLoc, Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1);
  
  gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, numLines * 2);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/2.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
<script id="vs" type="foo">
attribute vec4 position;
void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
}
</script>
<script id="fs" type="foo">
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 u_color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = u_color;
}
</script>
```

If you don't want to replace the entire buffer each time you can allocate a max size and use `gl.bufferSubData` although in my experience `gl.bufferData` is faster than `gl.bufferSubData` in most cases.

Also if you haven't check out http://webglfundamentals.org